# Getting correct values from variables in functions in Tkinter

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

This is likely a simple problem related to how variables stored in a dictionary are given values within a function.

I'm trying to get the value of a Boolean variable I'm storing in a dictionary `(self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"])` that I set to `"True"` in the code below.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk   # python3
from tkinter import BooleanVar

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)      
        self.Page1_data={"Step1Complete": BooleanVar()}          
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageFifteen): 
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")          
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        controller.title("Part B Data Collection")
        controller.geometry("600x500")
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to the Part B Test!", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Complete Step 1", command=self.MakeStep1Complete)
        button1.place(relx=0.385, rely=0.65)

    def MakeStep1Complete(self):

        Step1Complete=True
        self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"]=Step1Complete
        self.controller.show_frame("PageFifteen")




class PageFifteen(tk.Frame):



    def StatusCheck(self):
        Step1Complete=self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"]
        print("True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed -a ")
        print(Step1Complete)




    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Check the data", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.StatusCheck()

        tk.Label(self, text="Click on each of the buttons below to review the data you have inputted").place(relx=0.15, rely=0.12)  

        Step1Complete=self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"].get()
        print("True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed - b")
        print(Step1Complete)

        button17=tk.Button(self, text="Check if we did everything", 

command=self.StatusCheck)
        button17.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.75)        

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = SampleApp()
        app.mainloop()
```

When I execute the above (now edited per Florent's suggestions) code, I get the following results:

```
True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed -a 
False
True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed - b
False
True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed -a 
True
```

The first result is from the first execution of the `StatusCheck` function, where I simply call the function. The second result is from when I am explicitly executing the command `(Step1Complete=self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"].get())` that ought to (but doesn't) get the correct Boolean data. The third result, and the only result that gets the correct Boolean data, is generated when the user clicks the `"Check if we did everything"`, which calls the `StatusCheck` function from the `tk.Button` command config option.

Why might this happen? Why would the `StatusCheck` function not work the first time I execute it but then work the second time I execute it. Ideally, I'd like the code to immediately find that the `"Step1Complete"` variable has been set to `"True"` without having the user click a button.

I have reason to believe that the problem has something to do with which functions write values to variables, since I'm able to make the program work correctly when I set `"Step1Complete"` to `"True"` within the `__init__` function in the `StartPage` class.

Being a Python N00b, I know I must be missing something pretty obvious, but I really appreciate any help you could provide.

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. The methods aren't nested inside a class definition.

Comment: Bryan, I just fixed the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The short version of the answer is this: When you are using tkinter variables you need to use set and get functions to access the value of the variables. Also in an unrelated issue, in a class you don't need to define a function before calling it and it is better to have __init__ on top of your class (cf class PageFifteen).

Now, specifically for your code and why you get those prints: 
currently, you call 2 prints when creating the PageFifteen Frame:

- in the first on, you print a tk.BooleanVar, which gives you its handle and not its value (var.get() to print the value)
- in the second one, you correctly use get() and print the current value of a your var (which is the default of a BooleanVar: False)

Then you show StartPage, click on button and you overwrite your Booleanvar with the bool True, that's why your last StatusCheck works without a get.

In your code you need to replace:

```
def StatusCheck(self):
    Step1Complete=self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"]
    print("True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed -a ")
    print(Step1Complete)by
```

by:

```
def StatusCheck(self):
    Step1Complete=self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"].get()    
    print("True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed -a ")
    print(Step1Complete)
```

and

```
def MakeStep1Complete(self):
    Step1Complete=True
    self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"]=Step1Complete
    self.controller.show_frame("PageFifteen")
```

by:

```
def MakeStep1Complete(self):
    Step1Complete=True
    self.controller.Page1_data["Step1Complete"].set(Step1Complete)
    self.controller.show_frame("PageFifteen")
```

Comment: Hi Florent. I implemented your suggested changes, and am now getting the following output:                                                                                                          True or false: at Step 15, Step 1 completed - a
False
                                                                                                                   My question now is this: why doesn't the .set() command seem to change the value of "Step1Complete" from False to True?

Comment: Just had a thought: would having StatusCheck return the value of "Step1Complete" help?

Comment: With the modifications I sent you, you should get the following answers: False, False, True . If you don't want the first False you just have to suppress the self.StatusCheck() from your \__init__. or initialize self.Page1_data["Step1Complete"] as True by using self.Page1_data["Step1Complete"] .set(True) in the \__init__ function of  SampleApp. Currently, it is set to True only when you click the button17

Comment: I kind of thought that would be the case. Just to be clear: is there no other way to make the first answer "True" without either commenting out self.StatusCheck() or by initializing Step1Complete as True right from the get go? Either way, I really do appreciate your help, and I think I would be able to live with having the user click button17 to get Step1Complete's value.